# How does Google Generative Search Experience decide which question to answer?

Tags: nlp, google, search, question-answering

Examples below.

The question:

> Why is my preview monitor blank in Premiere Pro?

is answered by [Google Generative Search Experience](https://labs.google/sge/):

[image]

However, the question

> How do I change the video width and height in Premiere Pro?":

is not answered by Google Generative Search Experience: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Zaz.png

How does Google Generative Search Experience decide which question to answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're falling victim to A-B testing. When rolling out a new feature, companies often decide who and whether to present it based on various criteria (including random choice), and measuring user reactions.

Eg GSE is not available for me at all since I'm not in the US: "Search Labs isn’t available for your account right now".

Tomorrow your second question may be answered by SGE. And vice versa, your first question may stop being answered by SGE.

Comment: Thanks, typically A-B testing doesn't depend on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Right now based on my experience (Rolled out in India a month or so back) I think it's the following.

1. If Google can Determine a great answer to it by referencing some article where the steps are mentioned to something and is highly ranked, I'll get a more or less a summary of those steps in a more structured format.

[image]

2. If Google can't find a great answer to that, it'll more or less default to a search, while showing an option for me to initiate a generative search query.

If you look at the image below it doesn't use SGE because - the top result is a video (can't be summarized yet)

[image]

Hope this helps, again based on testing, don't have any other sources to quote.